# Time stamps (kyoto adlnormal and Kyoto adlerror dataset)

Tags: android-activity, timestamp

Please I am working with two datasets , kyoto adlnormal and kyoto adlerror dataset for healthcare activity recognition in dementia care. The kyoto adlnormal dataset has 5 activities simulating normal behavior whereas the kyoto adlerror dataset has the same actvities but with errors. Please how do i combine these two datasets to still preserve the temporal information.I tried using cancatenation and reshuffled it but my supervisor said it is not a good approach!. Find attached a screen shot of the two datasetS. The dates of collection are also differeent , for kyoto adlerror, the data is from 28/3/208 whereas the kyoto adnormal the data is from 27/2/2008.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6rwp.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQj9x.jpg)

This is what I have tried to do but not sure if it is a good practice

## Concatenate the datasets vertically

combined_df = pd.concat([kyoto_adlnormal, kyoto_adlerror], ignore_index=True)

combined_df